# Exe that just display fullscreen image

Tags: windows, image, exe, fullscreen

What is the fastest way to create a software that just have to show a fullscreen image on Windows?

It would be a simple exe that doesn't require other software like the .net framework

Comment: This depends on a lot of factors - which version of Windows you are developing for, for example. Consider Googling `<name of the programming platform you are using> full screen application`, there's likely going to be plenty of information already

Comment: Seach engine that leads you to the answer[Google](https://google.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save this as Hello.HTA, double click to run.

```
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="hello"
APPLICATIONNAME="hello"
BORDER="none"
BORDERSTYLE="normal"
CAPTION="no"
CONTEXTMENU="no"
INNERBORDER="no"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
NAVIGABLE="no"
SCROLL="no"
SCROLLFLAT="no"
SELECTION="yes"
SHOWINTASKBAR="no"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
SYSMENU="no"
VERSION="1.0"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize" />
<html>
<head>
<style>
body, html { margin:0; border:0 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.bing.com/hpwp/10f693963e63bb035ee9d4b6bbebc5ef" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does it also work on Windows XP?

Comment: Yes, it works on XP.

Comment: Is it ALT+F4 to exit?

Comment: That's really neat - have my vote!

Answer (score -1):

Delphi is very easy. There you have your GUI and then you can add a Picture element. Then u say, the picture should have the size of the windows and the windowmode is fullscreen. You dont need the .NET Framework or sth. else. If u load the programm Pascal you can free and legal develop with Pacal / Delphi. Do you want do do this? Then look and try..say if u need more help :)

Comment: I think this answer would be better if there was code

Comment: Hahaaa :) Let people work for you, dont say thank you and request for more

Comment: He dont need some code. He will drag and drop the TImage on the Form. Then set the propertys of this element:  Align: alClient, Picture: load your Picture. Select the Form in the propertysinspector, set the property of the form: WindowState: wsFullScreen.